# What's a good party composed of in Avernum 6?

Tags: avernum-6

I run the risk of being too general but so far, I have a slith soldier, a priest, a nephilim archer and a human rogue. It seems I don't have a mage, but is it needed to finish the game? I'm pretty sure you could finish any rpg with any party (albeit with different difficulties) but is it okay to have no mage? I thought the priest could function as a mage as well but realized it will be too much of a burden.

Just to clear things up as said in the comments, I just want to know if the game can be finished without a mage(and by finished I mean not having to save load a zillion times to get it right...more like I can beat a normal difficulty game without too much difficulty and with some challenge also).

Im worried on quest rewards that might focus on giving mage items/spells also. Are there lots of it?

Comment: As asked the question is too open-ended.  If you are having trouble with a specific party makeup, and want to know how to compensate for it, that would make a better question.  But just asking "Is this party OK?" won't get you much other than "Yes".

Comment: Disagreeing with the close votes here. Question in the title seems subjective, but he's wondering if the game can be won without a mage. Can it or can it not? It's an answer that only an expert on the game can give, and so I think it qualifies as a good question for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't gotten too far in the game yet (still inside the demo), but my Soldier/Rogue/Priest/Sorceror party has been pretty much slicing through everything they come across without too much trouble.

For me, the big decision was between an Archer and a Rogue. For that character slot, I wanted both ranged attacks and lockpicking ability, and decided to take the Rogue and give him points in Archery instead of melee weapons. Seems to be working out well so far.

Comment: what's the race of your rogue? im thinking of choosing a nephilim then just converting him to rogue for my archer/rogue needs then converting my other rogue into a mage. also, are there lots of mage weapons/spells given as quest rewards?

Comment: Definitely a Nephilim for a rogue or archer. The bonuses to dexterity and missile weapons is just too good to pass up, since that's almost entirely what either of those two classes will be based around. That's been the case in every Avernum/Exile game since the very beginning.

I haven't come across a ton of mage items as quest rewards yet, but then again, I haven't gotten too far in yet myself so it's entirely possible that this changes the further into the game you get.